# Как получить DocumentFile из файла из папки файлов приложения?

Tags: java, android

Я знаю для того чтобы получить DocumentFile из файла есть функция DocumentFile.fromFile:

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File(context.getFilesDir() + "/folder/", "file.txt" );
    if(!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
```

Но дело в том что как бы не "настоящий" DocumentFile например он не содержит родительского DocumentFile. Вообще не совсем понимаю вот это все с DocumentFile, например uri в полученном DocumentFile не настоящее только содержит путь к файлу, но это не достаточно. Я читал там должны быть привелегии и т.д., но я вроде это все делаю в разрешенной папке, почему ничего не работает, кто то может мне эту непонятную систему объяснить пожалуйста, я уже запутался?

Comment: У стартового каталога нет родителя - сама концепция document API предполагает доступ только к содержимому файла/каталога, выход за пределы невозможен. `DocumentFile.fromFile()`, по-моему, сделали для обратной совместимости с четвёртым андроидом, где SAF вообще не было, чтобы хоть как-то можно было сократить ветвления - о полной совместимости с документами и речи не идёт.

Comment: Так может мне можно получить DocumentFile самой файловой директории и потом уже искать нужный файл, например так df.findFile("file.txt"); Или не?

Comment: Можно, только перепрыгнуть сразу к файлу в подкаталогах нельзя, нужно перебирать весь путь до файла: `df.findFile("folder").findFile("file.txt")` и конечно же проверять каждый шаг на `null` - так как `findFile()` находит только существующие файлы/папки

Comment: спасибо, ну хоть что то